# Python: xml.dom.minidom empty nodeValue nonempty toxml() value

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have a line that gets the nodeValue of a Node:

```
parent.getElementsByTagName("Url")[0].nodeValue
```

that returns nothing:

```
<br/>
```

When I do:

```
parent.getElementsByTagName("Url")[0].toxml()
```

it returns:

```
< Url>www.something.com< /Url>
```

I am not sure what is going on here. Another data point: when I do nodeName instead of nodeValue it returns, as expected, Url.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
parent.getElementsByTagName('Url')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DOM Level 2 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) states that `nodeName` for an element node is the tag name, the `nodeValue` is always `null` and `attributes` is a `NamedNodeMap`, so this code behaves as expected.

Comment: @user1767754 I think your browser is kaputt, because the link is perfectly fine.